# How to use correctly use 是否?

Tags: translation, grammar

I'm not entirely sure what is suppose to follow 是否. For example, I'd like to say:

> I wasn't know (or wasn't sure) if you heard me clearly.

I'm not sure if this is how it should be translated:

> 我没确定你是否听清楚出我刚说的话

I'm also curious if this is correct:

> 我没确定你是否听到了我。

How should the above be properly translated? And, more importantly, how do I use 是否 in general?

Comment: In your English sentences, consider using whether instead of if :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

是否 roughly maps to *whether* in a yes-no interrogative sentence or clause.

For your sentence, you should use 不知道 or 不确定 instead of 没确定. 没确定 means *haven't confirmed yet*. Also 听得清 (could hear) is more polite than 听清了 (have heard). If the context allows, it is more natural to omit 我说的话.

> I wasn't sure if you could hear me clearly.
>
> 我不确定你是否听得清(我说的话)。

General usage of 是否 is pretty straight-forward. You can check out [Iciba](http://dj.iciba.com/%E6%98%AF%E5%90%A6-1.html) for examples.